# Swift 2 How do you add authorization header to POST request

Tags: post, swift2, authorization

When making a particular POST request, Firefox (FF) dev tools shows a req. header named "Authorization" with a value of "Bearer X" where X is the access token received upon login.  When I edit this request in FF and remove the "Authorization" line, I get a 400 error.  When I put it back in, 200 and all is well.  I haven't yet, however, figured out how to set this request header programmatically without getting 400.

Also, FF tools as a "Request Body" of  {"source":"desktop - profile 2015"}.  I'm assuming this is JSON.  I've tried posting this in several ways (see code) but have had no success.

```
// the following fields are set in the object "Request"'s initialization
let accessToken = "1,2,3456789012,3x4f560fa7a89e01a2;33ab4b4e5e67e8e9b9f0e1a23db45678f9a9a0ff" // replaced some characters for this StackOF posting
let authorization = "Bearer \(accessToken)"
let method = "POST"
let userID = "1234567"
let URL = NSURL(string: "https://www.somesite.com/apitun/profile/\(userID)hide")

// tried setting params to all of the following 4:
let params = ""
let params = "&_json={}"
let params = "&_json={\"source\":\"desktop profile - 2015\"}
let params = "&_json=%7B%22source%22%3A%22desktop%2Dprofile%202015%22%7D"

func execute() {
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
    if authorization != "" {
        request.addValue(authorization, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    }

    request.HTTPMethod = self.method
    request.HTTPBody = self.params.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    self.task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        (data, response, error) in
        NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().setCookies(self.cookies, forURL: self.URL, mainDocumentURL: nil)
        if error == nil {
            do {
                self.responseHeaders = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
                self.cookies = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookiesForURL(self.URL)!
                self.statusCode = self.responseHeaders.statusCode

                switch self.statusCode {

                case 200:
                    self.contentsOfURL = try NSString(contentsOfURL: self.URL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                case 400:
                    print("400: page not found")

                case 404:
                    print("404: page not found")

                case 407:
                    print("407: failed authenticate proxy credentials")

                default:
                    print("unable to get statusCode")

                }
            } catch {

            }
            self.isRequesting = false
        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    self.task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: fullURL)!)

let accessToken = "your access token"
request.setValue("Bearer \(accessToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

Comment: Recently had trouble with this `Authorization` header field name.

It is stated in this documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest#1776617 that `Authorization` header field name is an apple Reserved HTTP header, it should not be used or edited because as stated there: `If you set a value for one of these reserved headers, the system may ignore the value you set, or overwrite it with its own value, or simply not send it. Moreover, the exact behavior may change over time.`

Comment: I believe Apple will continue to support open standards like OAuth.